# Changing background of link when clicked using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have 4 links with background color that I need to be changed when I click, I use this code to change the background :

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#content_area').load($('.pm_class:first').attr('href'));

  $('.pm_class').click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).css('background-color', '#3B581E');
    $(this).css('color', '#fff');
    $('#content_area').hide().load(href).fadeIn('normal');
    return false;
  });
});
```

The issue is: when I click a different link the css in my jQuery is still applied to the previous link I clicked along with the second one. I need the first to return to the original state as shown in the image below. I need it to return back to be like the "send message" and "archive" links :

[jQuery issue](http://www.flickr.com/photos/wfareed/6707380979/)

Comment: your picture does not work as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS functions are objects, and can be assigned member variables.  These work like what in some C like languages is called a "static" local variable, meaning it retains its value between invocations.

```
$('pm_class').click(function () { switchBG($(this)) });

function switchBG (elem) {
    if (switchBG.prev) {
        switchBG.prev.css('background', '#ffffff');
    }
    elem.css('background', '#ffff00');
    switchBG.prev = elem;
}
```

You could do the same thing with a global, but this is tidier.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the style of all `.pm_class` elements back to the original, and then change the styles of `this` to the new style:

```
$('.pm_class').click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(".pm_class").css({
        backgroundColor: "oldColor",
        color: "oldColor"
    });
    $(this).css({
        backgroundColor: "#3B581E",
        color: "#fff"
    });
    $('#content_area').hide().load(href).fadeIn('normal');
    return false;
});
```

Note that I've consolidated your calls to the [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) method into one, as it will accept an object representing a map of CSS properties and values as an argument.